# Equivalent function in Oracle SQL for the Java Operator '%'

Tags: java, sql, oracle

What is the equivalent in Oracle SQL to have exactly same behavior of the Java % (Modulo) Operator?

Example Java:

```
System.out.println(9 % 4);  // 1
```

As known Oracle SQL provides *REMAINDER* and *MOD*:

```
REMAINDER(9,4)  /* 1 */
MOD(9,4)        /* 1 */
```

It is not clear to me what the appropriate equivalent is here and how to evidence it.

Comment: Given [JLS, §15.17.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) and the [documentation of OracleDB's `MOD` operation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm#i77996), Java's `%`-operation and OracleDB's `MOD` operation should be equivalent.

Comment: An interesting tid bid on the difference between `MOD` and `REMAINDER` can be found in the [documentation of OracleDB's `REMAINDER` operation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions133.htm): "*The `MOD` function is similar to `REMAINDER` except that it uses `FLOOR` in its formula, whereas `REMAINDER` uses `ROUND`*".

Comment: The Oracle documentation on REMAINDER is terrible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Turing85 mentioned the Java's `%`-[operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) and Oracle SQL's `MOD` [operation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm#i77996) seems be equivalent.

**Oracle**

```
REMAINDER(11,-4)   /* -1 */
REMAINDER(-11,-4)  /*  1 */
MOD(11,-4)         /*  3 */
MOD(-11,-4)        /* -3 */
```

**Java**

```
 11%-4            /*  3 */
-11%-4            /* -3 */
```